# Aplicação correta do font-face

Tags: html, css, css3, css-font-face

É sabido que as fontes do tipo `woff` e `woff2` não são suportadas por todos os navegadores, estou usando em minha página e no console do google chrome acusa problemas para baixar a fonte do tipo `woff2`, na no mozilla as do tipo `.woff`.

Alguém poderia me dizer por favor como utilizar estas fontes customizadas sem que estes tipos de erro apareçam no console? O ideal é usar só `TTF` e `EOT`.

Exemplo do erro no chrome:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Porém a fonte esta no diretório correto.

Comment: Esse erro **404 Not Found** é na localização do arquivo e não no suporte, provavelmente vc apontou o caminho relativo de maneira errada. Coloque o caminho completo assim `url(http://site/fonts/fonte.woff2)` por exemplo e teste.

Comment: Legal Guilherme, vou tentar!

Comment: Não sei se é o seu caso, mas se vc tiver construído sua classe assim também não vai funcionar:  `.className { @font-face { font-family: Helvetica; url(Helvetica.woff); } }`

Comment: não deu certo, o meu css esta na pasta dist/estilos/fonts.css e as fontes na pasta dist/fonts, tentei vários caminhos porém não funciona.

Comment: hugocsl você tem alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 0):

Pesquisei e encontrei a solução, as fontes woff2 e woff sempre ser devem vir antes das demais na folha de estilo.

Comment: Isso não explica o erro 404 e a questão da ordem deve ser por questões de *suporte vs retro-compatibilidade*, creio que seria melhor você citar, fontes pois nem tudo que lemos é de fato correto em blogs e afins. Se puder informar de onde obteve isto talvez possamos encontrar algo mais técnico para a informação.

Comment: Munir vc tem que escrever seu CSS pela ordem das coisas que vc quer chamar primeiro. Se vc colocar por ex. a fonte TTF na primeira linha se o seu browser tiver suporte ao formato TTF ela será a fonte carregada e os demais formatos ficam como *fallback*. Logo que se quer o formato WOFF2 ele tem que ser a primeira opção no `src: url` Deu pra entender?

Comment: isso mesmo hugocs!, foi o que eu fiz, obrigado a todos